# Insert order std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I would create an associative array (like std:: map) that stores the elements in order of insertion. I wrote this class:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class My_Map : public std::unordered_map<K,V>
{
 public:
 V& operator[]( const K&& key )
  {
    typename std::unordered_map<K,V>::iterator __i = find(key);
    if (__i == std::unordered_map<K,V>::end()) //se non l'ho trovato...
    {
      __i = insert(__i, std::make_pair(std::move(key), V()) );
      mHistory.push_back(__i);std::cout<<"Sto inserendo: "<<key<<std::endl;
    }
    return (*__i).second;
  }

  typename std::unordered_map<K,V>::iterator cbegin() const
  {
        return *mHistory.cbegin();
  }

  typename std::unordered_map<K,V>::iterator cend() const
  {
      return *mHistory.cend();
  }

  private:
    std::list<typename std::unordered_map<K,V>::iterator> mHistory;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    My_Map<string,int> myMap;


    myMap["1"] = 1;
    myMap["23"] = 23;
    myMap["-3"] = 3;
    myMap["23"] = 28;
    myMap["last element"] = 33;

    for (auto x = myMap.cbegin(); x != myMap.cend(); ++x)//{std::cout<<"sn dentro\n";}
        cout<<(*x).first <<"\t"<<x->second<<endl;
}
```

I used unordered_map instead std::map because std::map mix iterators when I insert new element.

This code have a problem: the for in main() fails with a segmentation fault. The iterators passed with cbegin() and cend() are not valid...why? What's wrong?

Comment: Check out Boost.multi_index, which is exactly what you propose.

Comment: There are also linked maps in [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct/).

Comment: It is strongly discouraged to derive from a container like you have (they don't have virtual destructors), and variable name with leading underscores are generally considered to be reserved for the compiler and standard library. I might be wrong but I am fairly sure that unordered map does not ensure insertion order, if you want that you could use a std::vector of std::pair however you will not have the access by key semantics as an associative array like those in PHP or whatever.

Comment: 11111: underscore+capital or double underscore are reserved by the implementation, the Standard says so, they're not "generally considered" to be reserved. They are, don't use them.

Comment: @11111: his class has a std::list to hold (and traverse) the insertion order.

Comment: Are there more operations for `My_Map` you aren't showing? Can you just replace it with a `vector<pair<string,int>>`?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you can't dereference an end iterator of a list. Secondly, I also doubt if `yourMap.cend` will be necessarily reachable from `yourMap.cbegin`.

It looks like you might need an adaptor for the list iterator that automatically dereferences the stored <strike>map iterator</strike> pointer to map item.

In any case, you need to iterate over the list, not from a random point in the unordered_map to another random point therein.

---

Also: adding elements can cause rehashing, which will **invalidate iterators** (but not pointers or references to elements). You should not even store iterators into an unordered_map.

Comment: There is a method to solve this problem without using boost_multiindex, for use the same std::map  insert syntax? (myMap[myKey] = myValue;)